# Book about a main character who can shapeshift into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am looking for a book that came out in hardback some time between 1994 and 2004, I think.  The book is about a main character who can shapeshift into a dragon.  There is a picture on the cover of the main character and an owl on a perch behind him.

Comment: Please add more details. This is quite vague at this point. Check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: It could be one of the _[Switchers Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switchers_Trilogy)_ books.

Comment: Shapeshifting to dragons is pretty common as are owls.  Some details about plot would be useful.

Comment: I'd suggest the *City of Dragons* books by Adrienne Wilder, except to my knowledge they were never available in hardback, and none of them included an owl that I recall.

Comment: I want to suggest T.A. Barron's *Merlin* books, but the fellow portrayed with owl and the shapeshifting dragon are different characters.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: unless you're conflating two different memories, this book does *not* match your description (Lindskold wrote about shapeshifting, but this is her first book and the main character is *not* a shapeshifter).

---

Could it be "Brother to Dragons, Companion to Owls" by Jane Lindskold? (The title is a pun on Job 30:29).

It *was* published in 1994, and while the cover on Amazon does not match, this one looks like it might:

[image: cover]

Comment: Can you provide details that suggest the pointers match?

Comment: @Edlothiad, I looked for the details and this looks like it is *not* the book. Yet when the OP mentioned shapeshifting, this title jumped to my mind - apparently I associate Lindskold with shapeshifting stories. Seeing as you're an older hand than I at scifi.SE, do you suggest I delete the answer? Or might the OP misremember like I did?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the first tome of a trilogy by Sarah Ash : The Lord of Snow and Shadows.

The cover was not as you described in my case, but it was a re-edition. I remember there being a story about rescuing a wounded owl.
The main character faces a dilemma where in order to use his power to shapeshift, he needs to drink blood, which he refuses to do. But as the (unwilling) leader of a warrior clan, he is expected to.

Comment: The owl is fairly prominent on the cover of _The Lord of Snow and Shadows_ and no protagonist.  One of her other books has a cover like what is described except the bird seems to be a hawk or falcon.